# How to use string of numbers as coordinate points of matrix R

Tags: r, matrix, coordinates

I am doing a for loop and I want to make a list of row coordinates (where for loop done staff) and use the list of coordinates later to delete those rows. I can not delete the corresponding rows in the loop since it shifts subsequent row upwards, which then will be skipped in next loop since i is incremented in next loop

```
coor <- list()

for (i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
    if (data[i,5] == "x"){
        "DO STAFF"
        coor  <- paste(coor, i, sep = ",")
        }
    }
data <- data[-c(),]
```

where `c()` should look like `c(10,20,30)`
but `coor` list is of string type ("10,20,30") and cant be used as subsequent coordinates separated with ","

Any suggestions for elegant way of doing it ?

PS Sorry for confusion, by "do staff" I meant my chunk of code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `for` loop for this problem. Posting data and expected output in the question will help understand your problem better.

Try this:

```
coor <- data[, 5] == 'x'
data[coor, "DO STAFF"]
data[!coor, ]  # delete matching rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
coor <- list("10,20,30")
idx <- as.numeric(as.vector(unlist(strsplit(unlist(coor),split = ','))))
data <- data[-idx,]
```

The second line transforms your list into a vector of numbers after splitting it at the commas.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as:

```
data[!data[,5] == "x",]
```

Remember everything in R is made to have vectorized solutions. The `for` function should be used in very rare cases.

Answer (score 0):

PS

I resolved it by creating a coor vector and using it when deleting rows

coor <- vector()

for (i in 1:dim(data)[1]){
if (data[i,5] == "x"){
"DO STAFF"
coor <- append(coor, i)
}
}
data <- data[-coor,]